# How to blink flash until the value in firebase is false

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage, flashlight

I want to keep blinking the flash forever until the value from firebase database is false. This is what I tried:

```java
boolean mIsOn = false;
    CameraManager camManager;
    String cameraId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ha);
        camManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            cameraId = camManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://vehiclcocity-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/").getReference().child("value").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                mIsOn = snapshot.getValue(boolean.class);
                Log.d("mIsOn", mIsOn + "");
                if (mIsOn){
                    try {
                        blink();
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else {
                    try {
                        camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId,false); //Turn off
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(HA.this, "" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        try {
            camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId,false); //Turn off
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        try {
            camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId,mIsOn); //Turn to last state
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onResume();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void blink() throws CameraAccessException {
        
        String str = "01010101010101010101010101010101010101010101";
        String str2 = str + str + str + str + str + str + str + str + str + str + str + str + str + str + str + str + str + str + str;
        String myString = str2 + str2 + str2 + str2 + str2 + str2 + str2 + str2 + str2 + str2 + str2 + str2 + str2 + str2 + str2 + str2 + str2 + str2 + str2;
        long blinkDelay = 100; //Delay in ms
        for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
            Log.d("isOnTorch",mIsOn + "");
            if (myString.charAt(i) == '0') {
                camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId,true);
            } else {
                camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId,false);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Problem:**
This works as expected when the value in database is true. But, as soon as the value becomes false, the flash does not stop. It stops after the entire pattern has ended and that is not I want. **I want to stop the blink effect as soon the value becomes false**. I have surely missed something out.

Comment: Unrelated: I just wanted to comment on your "giphy" question/self answer: Thing is: it is perfectly okay to ask a question with the intention of a self answer ... but then make sure that the question itself is written up in a good way. Yours wasnt. It read like the typical low quality "somebody do my work for me and give me the codez" request by some 1st day newbie. So: try to frame up a valid, question like "can someone give me a comprehensive example how to use the giphy API" or sth like that.

Comment: And it typically helps to either: have the answer content prepared, so you can answer quickly yourself. Or to write a short comment to the question explaining that you intend to self answer.